# Angular directive transclude create new scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create directive component for modal windows, which take care about modal behaviour such as opening, closing, taking care of zIndex etc.

Content of modal components is controlled by Controller.
So far idea is good, but when i try to have

```
<modal ng-controller="MyController">
  Some content which will be transcluded with dynamic {{value}} from MyController
</modal>
```

It failed and does not render `{{value}}`
I have to wrap modal into controller

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <modal>
    Some content which will be transcluded with dynamic {{value}} from MyController
  </modal>
</div>
```

Is there any way, how to make first example works, or it is impossible and why angular do it that way?

There is full example with plunker at the end.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.directive("modal", function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    transclude:true,
    scope: false,
    template:'<div class="modal">Modal scope {{$id}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function($scope) {
      console.log("directive scope ", $scope.$id)
    }
  }  
})

app.controller('DetailControl', function($scope, $location) {
  console.log("controller scope ", $scope.$id)
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

and this HTML

```
<body>
main scope {{$id}}

Controller on same element as modal<br>

<modal ng-controller="DetailControl">
  <div>
    content scope (transclude) {{$id}}<br>
    Some content of modal window. The name is {{name || '-unknown-'}}
  </div>
</modal>

Controller outside modal
<div ng-controller="DetailControl">
  Controller scope {{$id}}
  <modal>
    <div>
      content scope (transclude) {{$id}}<br>
      Some content of modal window. The name is {{name || '-unknown-'}}
    </div>
  </modal>
</div>
<body>
```

here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/WOgZKB3e0bQUASMhFVOp?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

try use transclude with passing scope :
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

transcludeFn -> scope

"transcludeFn - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope. The scope can be overridden by an optional first argument. This is the same as the $transclude parameter of directive controllers. function([scope], cloneLinkingFn)."

Comment: Can you try to apply it on Plunker? I am not sure how implment that

Comment: This has solved a long-standing problem for me.  I'd upvote more than once if I could!  Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the [`ngController`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6288cf5ca471b0615a026fdb4db3ba242c9d8f88/src/ng/directive/ngController.js) directive creates it's own scope.  When you do `<modal ng-controller="MyController">` the `ngController` scope is a sibling to `modal` so `modal` can't see over (sideways in a sense) into that controller.

It works when `ngController` is a parent because you're using `scope: false` which causes your directive to inherit it's scope from its parent.

**Rather than use a separate `ngController` directive you can attach a controller to your directive**:

```
  app.directive("modal", function() {
    return {
      controller: function($scope, $location) {
        console.log("controller scope ", $scope.$id)
        $scope.name = 'World';
     }
  }
```

This approach will give your directive good encapsulation as it no longer will depend on an external controller- which is good.  One plus is you no longer need to coordinate multiple scopes.

If you need multiple directives to communicate you can use [`require`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to allow multiple directives to all share access to one parent directive's controller.  This is the approach Angular internally takes (for instance in ['ng-switch`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/90f87072e83234ae366cfeb3c281503c31dad738/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js))

Comment: I understand this access, but I need to control content of modal from many different places of application.

Comment: Could you give an example that `require` doesn't address?  With more details I could give you a more fine grained answer.

Comment: I have modal on lot of places across whole application. And they have different logic inside. From simple content modal to complex forms and logic. That is why i want to modal directive just encapsulate bahaviour of opening/closing and business logic is inside many different controllers. In short: Modal does not know anything about content.

Comment: Angular recommends business logic live inside a service/provider.  If it was me that'd be the direction I'd look.  If you haven't seen it, there's a great video from the Angular team that discusses this amongst many other things- [Angular Best Practices Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY)